# How can I disable CORB(Cross-Origin Read Blocking) on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to serve GeoServer WMS service locally on top of Openlayers. I encounter an error that says `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response`. How can I serve the Web Map Service layers locally or disable the CORB?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers

Comment: @mplungjan What does it mean? How can I remove this constraint?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question to ask when you get a security-related message is not "how do I disable security?" it should be "how do I do what I want to do securely?"

Comment: Did you read the page i sent you? If you are not planning to FIX the issue, then  `You can confirm if a problem is due to CORB by temporarily disabling it, by starting Chrome with the following command line flag:
--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating`

Comment: @HereticMonkey How do I do that securely then? If you know how?

Comment: @mplungjan I am sending this file to my instructor, so it won't work for his machine?

Comment: Use the same origin through a reverse proxy: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect Chrome is incorrectly blocking a response and that this is disrupting the behavior of a website, please file a Chromium bug describing the incorrectly blocked response (both the headers and body) and/or the URL serving it. You can confirm if a problem is due to CORB by temporarily disabling it, by starting Chrome with the following command line flag:

--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

Source: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/